# How to refresh the parent widget when I change data from a Modal Bottomsheet?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I try to refresh `_currentValue` when I open a modal bottom sheet and I change the value from state full widget `depense()`.

Here is my code

```
new RaisedButton(
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
elevation: 5,
highlightElevation: 10,
color: Colors.white,
splashColor: Colors.white,
    child :  new  Text("${_currentValue}",textAlign: TextAlign.center,  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize:  SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal! * 4)),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all (15.0),
        onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
        showMaterialModalBottomSheet(isDismissible: true,
        shape:  RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius:
        BorderRadius.circular(15)),
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => depense()
          );
          });
          }),
```

---

```
class depense extends StatefulWidget {
  const depense({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<depense> createState() => _depenseState();
}

class _depenseState extends State<depense> {

  int _currentValue = 5;
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/1.8,
        child :
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20,right:20),
            child:
          
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: NumberPicker(
                  axis: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemHeight: 70,
                  itemWidth: 70,
                  step: 1,
                  selectedTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                    color: Color(0xff61d3cb),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                  ),
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 12.0,
                  ),
                  value: _currentValue,
                  minValue: 0,
                  maxValue: 1000,

                  onChanged: (v) {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentValue = v;

                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
             
            ));
  }
}
```

If I add the widget build from depense state full widget directly on the modalbottomsheet  like bellow, `Text("${_currentValue}"` is upgrade but NumberPicker return to initial value...
But when I create the statefull widget I can use NumberPicker but not refresh data...

```
 new RaisedButton(

  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
  elevation: 5,
  highlightElevation: 10,
  color: Colors.white,
  splashColor: Colors.white,
  child :  new  Text("${_currentValue}",textAlign: TextAlign.center,  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize:  SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal! * 4)),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all (15.0),
  onPressed: () {


setState(() {
  showMaterialModalBottomSheet(isDismissible: true,
      shape:  RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius:
          BorderRadius.circular(15)),

      context: context,
      builder: (context) =>  Container(


          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/1.8,

          child :
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20,right:20),
              child:
           
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: NumberPicker(
                          axis: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemHeight: 70,
                          itemWidth: 70,
                          step: 1,
                          selectedTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30.0,
                            color: Color(0xff61d3cb),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          ),
                          textStyle: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                          ),
                          value: _currentValue,
                          minValue: 0,
                          maxValue: 1000,

                          onChanged: (v) {
                            setState(() {
                              _currentValue = v;

                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
          ))
  );
});

                                      }),
```

Comment: what is your issue ? I didn't get it!

Comment: When I use NumberPicker to pick a new _currentValue, the value isn't send to new  Text("${_currentValue}", from my raisedbutton who is on an other statefull widget

Comment: I have add more information on the post about my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need define `currentValue` in your main class and pass a function to `depense` class like this:

```
class depense extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(int) onChange; //<-- add this
  const depense({Key? key, required this.onChange}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<depense> createState() => _depenseState();
}

class _depenseState extends State<depense> {
  int _currentValue = 5;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.8,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: NumberPicker(
              axis: Axis.horizontal,
              itemHeight: 70,
              itemWidth: 70,
              step: 1,
              selectedTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30.0,
                color: Color(0xff61d3cb),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
              ),
              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 12.0,
              ),
              value: _currentValue,
              minValue: 0,
              maxValue: 1000,
              onChanged: (v) {
                widget.onChange(v);
                setState(() {
                  _currentValue = v;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
 RaisedButton(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      elevation: 5,
      highlightElevation: 10,
      color: Colors.white,
      splashColor: Colors.white,
      child: new Text("${_currentValue}",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              fontSize: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal! * 4)),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
              isDismissible: true,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => depense(onChange:(value){
                 setState(() {
                     _currentValue = value;
                 });
              }));
        });
      })
```

Comment: Sorry this isn't working totally. _currentValue is well refresh but NumberPicker not keep the value, after selected value, it return to init value.

Comment: The problem with this code is when I move my finger to select a number the picker is like forced to return to init value. When I physically move the picker, it refresh the _currentvalue but when I release my finger, the picker return to inital value

Comment: I update my answer, check it out. @Nitneuq

Comment: Thank you ! It's ok with that :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like _currentValue is a local state variable of the dispense class and you have another variable by same name in parent class also. Changes in local state variables are not reflected in parent widgets.

Usually, you should use any state management libraries in such scenarios, but a simple solution can be to pass a callback function from RaisedButton to dispense widget which will return its value.

```
class depense extends StatefulWidget {
   Function changeCurrentValue(int val);

  const depense({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<depense> createState() => _depenseState();
}

class _depenseState extends State<depense> {
   ...

    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/1.8,
        child :
        ...
        onChanged: (v) {
           widget.changeCurrentValue(v);
       }
```

In RaisedButton

```
int _currentValue = 5;

void changeCurrentValue(int v){
   setState(() {
       _currentValue = v;
    })
}

new RaisedButton(
   ...
   showMaterialModalBottomSheet(isDismissible: true,
        shape:  RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius:
        BorderRadius.circular(15)),
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => depense(changeCurrentValue: changeCurrentValue)
    ....
```

Comment: Sorry I have an error with  Function changeCurrentValue(int val); -> changeCurrentValue' must have a method body because 'depense' isn't abstract.